# Stricly non-negative constraint scipy minimize

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

I'm trying to use the minimize function from scipy to do curve fitting.

I have a 4-parameter equation with bounds constraints on each of them and I'd like to add the constraint that *param1* is different from *param2* (and if possible *param2* > *param1*). From what I understood, I have to use scipy.optimize.minimize with bound and constraints. But the constraints can only be equality (to 0) or inequality (non-negative, >= 0).

So if I set the constraint function to that (params are store in an array):

```
cons = {"type": "ineq", "fun": lambda x: x[1] - x[0]}
```

in case x[1] and x[0] are equal, the inequality constraint doesn't apply. Actually I don't really understand why there is no "strictly positive" constraint...

A workaround could be to add some very small residue to this "p[1] - p[0]" but isn't there a cleanest solution??

Cheers

Comment: In numerical computing, there is no difference in `>` and `>=`. For example `x[0] = x[1]+10**-100` implies `x[0]>x[1]`. However, under machine precision (which can only handle differences around the order of `10**-15`), `x[0] = x[1]+10**-100` is interpreted as `x[0]==x[1]`. If you really want a strict inequality you must introduce a (small) residue.

Comment: *"Actually I don't really understand why there is no "strictly positive" constraint..."* Think about this example: for a scalar x, minimize x**2, subject to the constraint x > 0.  What is the solution?